# What's the python __all__ module level variable for?

Tags: python, namespaces

I've seen it a lot in python/Lib source code but I don't know what it is for.

I thought it was used to limit accessible members of of a module. So only the elements at `__all__` will show up when `dir(module)`.

I did a little example and saw it was not working as I expected.

So... What's the python `__all__` module level variable for?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It has two purposes:

1. Anybody who reads the source will know what the exposed public API is. It doesn't *prevent* them from poking around in private declarations, but does provide a good warning not to.
2. When using `from mod import *`, only names listed in `__all__` will be imported. This is not as important, in my opinion, because importing everything is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: Not just anybody, also anything. Some api documentation tools respect `__all__`. pydoc does, and I'm pretty sure epydoc and the like also do.

Comment: The public variables in a '.py' is available in another file when we do a 'import *', even if they are not included in the __all__.can any one please clarify about this..?

Comment: Sphinx also respects ``__all__``

Answer (score 8):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

> Now what happens when the user writes
>   `from sound.effects import *`? Ideally,
>   one would hope that this somehow goes
>   out to the filesystem, finds which
>   submodules are present in the package,
>   and imports them all. This could take
>   a long time and importing sub-modules
>   might have unwanted side-effects that
>   should only happen when the sub-module
>   is explicitly imported.
>
> The only solution is for the package
>   author to provide an explicit index of
>   the package. The import statement uses
>   the following convention: if a
>   package’s `__init__.py` code defines a
>   list named `__all__`, it is taken to be
>   the list of module names that should
>   be imported when `from package import *`
>   is encountered. It is up to the
>   package author to keep this list
>   up-to-date when a new version of the
>   package is released. Package authors
>   may also decide not to support it, if
>   they don’t see a use for importing *
>   from their package.

Answer (score 4):

It controls what you get pulled into your namepsace when you

```
from blah import *
```

See [Importing * from a Package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)