# What is good practice way of data hiding in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is good practice way of data hiding in python ? Is it the same as java ?
private is with double underscore ?
protected is with single underscore ?
public function is possible, member public is not recommended ?
Right ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047122/python-private-function-coding-convention/15072306

Comment: Perl culture is like python in this respect, but Perl expresses the
sentiment a bit differently. As the Camel book puts it,

`a Perl module would prefer that you stayed out of its living room
  because you weren't invited, not because it has a shotgun.` (from link in comment above)

Answer (score 2):

The concept of data hiding does not really exist in python.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.