# What are the rules for __all__ and relative imports?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Inside a package I am using a few checks inside each module directory's `__init__.py` to see whether the environment is sane and then use `from . import mod1` for nested modules (`mod1` here). Each of the module directories in turn contains an `__init__.py` (obviously) which will import the next lower level (if any).

Some of the `__init__.py` contain `__all__` arrays to only expose certain names upon `import`.

Let's say I have the following "main" script (`spam.py`):

```
import os, sys

if (sys.version_info[0] != 2) or (sys.version_info < (2,7)):
    sys.exit("...")
else:
    import pkgname

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the following `pkgname/__init__.py`:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    from . import db
    from os.path import dirname, realpath
    sys.modules[__name__].__all__ = ['inipath']
    sys.modules[__name__].__dict__['inipath'] = dirname(realpath(__file__)) + '.ini'
```

and the following `pkgname/db/__init__.py`:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    import sqlite3
    # ...
foobar = { 'spam' : 'egg' }

__all__ = ["foobar"]
```

will the symbol `pkgname.db.foobar` be visible despite the `__all__` array in `pkgname/__init__.py`? I.e. does the `__all__` array only affect the immediate module or also any lower level?

Which rules govern Python's behavior here? I tried some searches but came up empty-handed. Possibly I used the wrong searches (`__all__`, `python`, `relative import`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__all__` has no effect in the case you're describing.  It only affects what happens when you do `from package import *`.  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) as well as [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187583/whats-the-python-all-module-level-variable-for) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python) (which I found by googling `python __all__`).

Comment: I used all of the search terms in various combinations but didn't come up with that link. Thanks. Also thanks for the swift answer. So as I understand it now `__all__` is only relevant with `*`, never for anything else.