# When create an optimizer in Tensorflow, how to deal with AttributeError happens?

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, deep-learning, attributeerror

I try to incorporate a self-designed optimization algorithm PSGLD into TensorFlow. And that algorithm is similar to the concept of RMSProp. So I didn't create a new Op, but complement PSGLD following RMSProp. My procedure of incorporating is as follows:

1. In Python side, create a `psgld.py` under the folder of `tensorflow\python\training`,which represents the Python wrapper. And in `psgld.py`, define the class of `PSGLDOptimizer`.

   `class PSGLDOptimizer(optimizer.Optimizer)`
2. Then, in `tensorflow\python\training\training_ops.py`, define the shape function of `_ApplyPSGLDShape` and `_SparseApplyPSGLD`, for dense and sparse circumstances respectively.
3. For C++ side, in `tensorflow\core\ops\training_ops.cc`, define the input, output and attribute of ApplyPSGLD Op:
   `REGISTER_OP("ApplyPSGLD")
   .Input("var: Ref(T)")
   .Input("ms: Ref(T)")
   .Input("mom: Ref(T)")
   .Input("lr: T")
   .Input("decay: T")
   .Input("epsilon: T")
   .Input("grad: T")
   .Output("out: Ref(T)")
   .Attr("T: numbertype")
   .Attr("use_locking: bool = false")`
4. Meanwhile, also define `ApplyPSGLD` in the header file of  `tensorflow\core\kernels\training_ops.h`

   `template <typename Device, typename T>
   struct ApplyPSGLD {
   ...
   };`
5. To realize the computation of our algorithm on C++ side, complement corresponding code in the kernel of `tensorflow\core\kernels\training_ops.cc`.

After all, when I run `tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py`, and the optimizer is adjusted,

`optimizer = tf.train.PSGLDOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=batch)`

an AttributeError happens:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PSGLDOptimizer'`

And the environment is TF-0.9, cudnn5. So I ask if someone can give me any advice on this issue or the whole procedure of adding an optimizer.

Comment: Did you recompile Tensorflow with your changes? (You need to build from source first)

Comment: `@OlivierMoindrot`  I have only added a import `PSGLDOptimizer` to the original `tensorflow\python\training\training.py`, defined `ApplyPSGLD` and realized its algorithm in C++ side in `tensorflow\core\kernels\training_ops.cc`. I am not sure if that is enough. Could you be more specific about "recompile"?

Comment: When you modify the TensorFlow code you need to recompile it again, to be able to use it. Check [the installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources) to install from source, then modify the source code, and finally recompile the code with your modifications. Recompiling means creating the pip package with `bazel` and installing it.

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming that you've rebuilt TensorFlow from source, as [Olivier suggested in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694292/when-create-an-optimizer-in-tensorflow-how-to-deal-with-attributeerror-happens#comment64768151_38694292), and you are trying to construct your optimizer as `optimizer = tf.train.PSGLDOptimizer(...)`.)

To add a symbol to the `tf.train` namespace, you have to do the following:

1. Add an explicit import to the file [`tensorflow/python/training/training.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27eeb441bad8bcaa1bcba42a4b4ee49fb50ea0d3/tensorflow/python/training/training.py). In that file, you can see imports for, e.g., the [`tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27eeb441bad8bcaa1bcba42a4b4ee49fb50ea0d3/tensorflow/python/training/training.py#L160) class.
2. Either:

   1. Add documentation for your new class, and add `@@PSGLDOptimizer` to the module docstring. The corresponding line for `tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer` is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27eeb441bad8bcaa1bcba42a4b4ee49fb50ea0d3/tensorflow/python/training/training.py#L36). This marks the class as a publicly documented API symbol.
   2. Add an exception to the [whitelist](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27eeb441bad8bcaa1bcba42a4b4ee49fb50ea0d3/tensorflow/python/training/training.py#L222) of symbols that are added to [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2187583/3574081) in that file. For example, [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27eeb441bad8bcaa1bcba42a4b4ee49fb50ea0d3/tensorflow/python/training/training.py#L231) whitelists the symbol `tf.train.LooperThread`.

For most TensorFlow modules*, the rule is that a symbol can appear in `__all__` if it is either (i) publicly documented, or (ii) explicitly whitelisted. If neither condition holds, it will not be accessible through a `tf.*` name. This is intended to keep the API surface small, and avoid exposing private implementation details that might change between versions.

* Note however that this is a work in progress. At present, a method is considered to be stable only if it is documented in the [public API docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/index.html).